# Padding invalid when decrypting stream

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a stream (coming from a file) using AesManaged. I can encrypt the file without error, but on decryption I get the following CryptographicException:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be
>   removed.

The exception is raised when the CryptoStream is being disposed. I use the following to encrypt the input data:

```
public byte[] Encrypt(Stream plain)
{
    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    using( var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream() )
    {
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = _myAes.CreateEncryptor(_myAes.Key, _myAes.IV))
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (BinaryWriter swEncrypt = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            int buf_size = 32768;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buf_size];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = plain.Read(buffer, 0, buf_size)) > 0)
            {
                swEncrypt.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And this to decrypt the data:

```
public byte[] Decrypt(Stream cipherText)
{

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = _myAes.CreateDecryptor(_myAes.Key, _myAes.IV))
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (BinaryWriter swDecrypt = new BinaryWriter(csDecrypt))
        {
            int buf_size = 32768;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buf_size];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = cipherText.Read(buffer, 0, buf_size)) > 0)
            {
                swDecrypt.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Any ideas about why this exception is coming up would be great. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is where the Aes object was created, note the Key and IV are just set to their current values temporarily, it is not the real key that will be used:

```
private Crypto()
{
    _myAes = new AesManaged();
    _myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    _myAes.KeySize = 128;
    _myAes.Key = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)'B', 128 / 8).ToArray();
    _myAes.IV = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)'C', 128 / 8).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you create _myAes?

Comment: @SimonJ - I added the snippet where I instantiate that object.

Comment: This error can be caused by many things. Most likely is that you are using the wrong key or IV. It can also be caused by data corruption.

Comment: @GregS - I changed it to use the fixed key and IV shown above, so those should be the same. I am taking the file and uploading it to AmazonS3, and I have tried it several times so I don't know how the data would be corrupted unless I am doing something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I got this exception when I tried to decrypt a buffer whose length was not a multiple of 16 bytes.

Did you try calling `Flush` on the `CryptoStream` before it is disposed? Possibly, if it isn't flushed then it ends up trying to decrypt a buffer with a non-aligned length.

And another note - I don't know if this will solve your problem, but when you create a `CryptoStream` in order to decrypt the buffer, shouldn't you be using `CryptoStreamMode.Read` instead of `CryptoStreamMode.Write`?

Comment: The way I originally tried used the Read mode, but I get the same exception. 
I tried calling `Flush` and `FlushFinalBlock` on the `CryptoStream` in both encrypting and decrypting and it still threw the same exception.

Comment: Also I should point out that when I change it to `CryptoSteamMode.Read`, it throws the exception when I read from the stream instead of when it is being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you finish the `CryptoStream` cleanly on the write side.  You may need to call `FlushFinalBlock()` to ensure that the end-of-stream padding is written through -- otherwise, you are likely to end up missing the final block of the stream, which will result in an invalid padding exception.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that FlushFinalBlock gets called when the CryptoStream is disposed, but it should be done explicitly IMHO for clarity.

Comment: I tried calling `FlushFinalBlock()` explicitly in the `Encrypt` method but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant to post something after 4 years but, you should try to set padding to none. I got the same problem with 3DES and the issue got solved with that (but make sure the length of data to be decrypted is correct...)

```
private Crypto()
{
    _myAes = new AesManaged();
    _myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.none; //rather than _myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    _myAes.KeySize = 128;
    _myAes.Key = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)'B', 128 / 8).ToArray();
    _myAes.IV = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)'C', 128 / 8).ToArray();
}
```